# writing dataframe to bigquery using to_gbq() get TypeError: initiate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-lab

When I try to upload a dataset to bigquery using to_gbq() from a jupyterlab env I get an error "TypeError: initiate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'". There appears to be a timeout option deep inside the to_gbq function so I don't really understand why there is an issue.

```
from pandas.io import gbq
dataframe.to_gbq('bq_folder.data', 
            project,
            chunksize=10000,
            if_exists='replace'
            )
```

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_gbq(self, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials)
   1533         from pandas.io import gbq
   1534 
-> 1535         gbq.to_gbq(
   1536             self,
   1537             destination_table,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials, verbose, private_key)
    204 ) -> None:
    205     pandas_gbq = _try_import()
--> 206     pandas_gbq.to_gbq(
    207         dataframe,
    208         destination_table,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials, verbose, private_key)
   1202         return
   1203 
-> 1204     connector.load_data(
   1205         dataframe,
   1206         dataset_id,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in load_data(self, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize, schema, progress_bar)
    627             if progress_bar and tqdm:
    628                 chunks = tqdm.tqdm(chunks)
--> 629             for remaining_rows in chunks:
    630                 logger.info(
    631                     "\r{} out of {} rows loaded.".format(

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py in __iter__(self)
   1178 
   1179         try:
-> 1180             for obj in iterable:
   1181                 yield obj
   1182                 # Update and possibly print the progressbar.

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_gbq/load.py in load_chunks(client, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize, schema, location)
     76         try:
     77             yield remaining_rows
---> 78             client.load_table_from_file(
     79                 chunk_buffer,
     80                 destination_table,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in load_table_from_file(self, file_obj, destination, rewind, size, num_retries, job_id, job_id_prefix, location, project, job_config, timeout)
   2445         try:
   2446             if size is None or size >= _MAX_MULTIPART_SIZE:
-> 2447                 response = self._do_resumable_upload(
   2448                     file_obj, job_resource, num_retries, timeout, project=project
   2449                 )

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in _do_resumable_upload(self, stream, metadata, num_retries, timeout, project)
   2862             is uploaded.
   2863         """
-> 2864         upload, transport = self._initiate_resumable_upload(
   2865             stream, metadata, num_retries, timeout, project=project
   2866         )
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in _initiate_resumable_upload(self, stream, metadata, num_retries, timeout, project)
   2936             )
   2937 
-> 2938         upload.initiate(
   2939             transport,
   2940             stream,

TypeError: initiate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

I tried switching from version 3.1.0 to 2.31.0 but that didn't work.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you done a search for this error on Stack Overflow and elsewhere? There are many posts, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082277).  Github also has threads.

Comment: Your code worked for me, I'm using the following versions of pandas and bigquery. Versions used:  `pandas==1.3.5, pandas-gbq==0.17.5, google-cloud-bigquery==3.1.0`. What versions of pandas, pandas-gbq and bigquery are you using?

Comment: Thank you for checking! I am using `pandas==1.4.2, pandas_gbq==0.17.5, bigquery==2.31.0` Are there any other dependencies that I may be missing?

Comment: I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68204482/typeerror-initiate-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-timeout) which is exactly the same with yours. The resolution is the same with the post that @AlexK provided.

Comment: Can you try reinstalling `google-resumable-media` and `google-cloud-storage`? I'm using the latest versions for both and code still works fine with me.